# Can't bind to 'target' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: angular

I am getting this error while implementing collapse feature:

> Error:  Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'target' since it isn't a
>   known property of 'div'

app.component.html:

```
<div *ngFor = "let ele of elements; let RowIndex = index">
    {{ele.name}} 
    <button data-toggle="collapse" 
            data-target="#demo{{RowIndex}}">Toggle
    </button>
    <div id="demo{{RowIndex}}" class="collapse">Lorem Ipsum</div>

</div>
```

But if I simply use `data-target="#demo"` , that is working fine. But when I am binding `{{RowIndex}}` than its showing error.

Comment: Why you need data attributes in angular?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

You missed property binding

```
<button data-toggle="collapse" 
        [attr.data-target]="'#demo'+ RowIndex">Toggle
</button>


<button (click)="clickMe($event)">Toggle</button>

clickMe(value){
    value.srcElement.innerHTML="Clicked";

  }
```

Comment: I didnt get you. elaborate

Comment: i want that my text 'Toggle' which is written on the button, will changeable when I clicked on the button while toggle.

Comment: you want to change from component or from where?

Comment: whatever will be the easiest way. I have both options '.ts' and '.html' .

Comment: when you want to handle it pls tell I will help/

Comment: when i click on button, the text should change.

Answer (score 52):

Use angular's attribute binding syntax.

Use one of the following:

```
<button data-toggle="collapse" 
        attr.data-target="#demo{{RowIndex}}">Toggle
</button>
```

or

```
<button data-toggle="collapse" 
        [attr.data-target]="'#demo' + RowIndex">Toggle
</button>
```

Comment: Just to make things clear, it doesn't count as a duplicate of your answer if you edit it after the fact. This was my answer before you edited, not that I care.

Answer (score 3):

use property binding :
attr.data-target="{{your-target}}"

Answer (score -1):

You can use href tag instead of div. you can check the below code

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let service of servicesArr;let i = index">
  <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#{{i}}{{service.name}}">{{service.label}}</a>
  <div id="{{i}}{{service.name}}" class="collapse">
     Lorem ipsum dolor text....
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="opciones">

 <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Opciones </th>
 <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item" class="text-center" role="button">  
  <a [routerLink]="['/panel/clientes',item._id]" matTooltip="Editar"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i></a>&nbsp;
  <a role="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#delete-{{item._id}}" matTooltip="Borrar"><i class="bi bi-trash-fill"></i></a>
  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade"  id="delete-{{item._id}}" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  ....**strong text**    
  </div>

 </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).