# data-hover angular2 not working

Tags: html, css, angular

Angular doesn't recognize data-hover.

Can't bind to 'data-hover' since it isn't a known property of 'span'

I have tried span, div no luck.
Existing page relies heavily on data-hover, so rewriting is not an option.

```
<a class="main-item" routerLink='{{ item?.url}}'>
    <span class="main-item-hover" data-hover="{{item?.label}}">{{item?.label}}</span>
</a>
```

This piece of code works perfectly without angular

EDIT :

```
.main-item-hover:before {
  content: attr(data-hover);
  font-weight: 600;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}
```

This is how data hover is used in css.

Ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for `title=`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to rewrite your code using square brackets along with property binding as

```
<a class="main-item" [routerLink]="item?.url">
  <span class="main-item-hover" [attr.data-hover]="item?.label">
    {{ item?.label }}
  </span>
</a>
```

plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/v49Qe7FInPToKXf952Et?p=preview

Comment: that was the first thing i tried before posting, same thing  [ERROR ->][data-hover]="item?.label">{{item?.label}}</span>

Comment: `attr` property binding should be added, I updated my original answer and added plunker with slightly different CSS, just to show CSS `content`

Comment: i have totally forgotten about attr. part. I still am not sure when attr is needed and when not. Oh well thanks alot

Comment: actually this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43386590/cant-bind-to-target-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-div#43386609) helped me to recall it, of course I upvoted @Aravind's answer as well :)