# ngx-translate: how to 'translate' a html attribute?

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I've implemented ngx-translate in my Angular-Cli app and works fine when I do something like:

```
<div>{{ 'some.value' | translate }}</div>
```

But how can I go about translating an attribute of an HTML component?
Something like:

```
<div data-text="{{ 'some.value' | translate }}"></div>
```

(this code above doesn't work)

Thanks in advance for any help provided...

**JB**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What error are you getting?

The code, as it appears, should work, but there's also another option to try:

```
<div [data-text]="'some.value' | translate"></div>
```

Off the top of my head, I'd guess you're getting an error like `'data-text' is not a property of <div>`, in which case it's not an ngx-translate issue but a missing `imports` in your `.component.ts` file that could add the missing attribute.

Comment: Thanks for help +MCattle.
That was more or less the error I was getting. Found this helpful link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43386590/cant-bind-to-target-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-div

Turns out doing this solved the issue:

`<div attr.data-text="{{ 'some.value' | translate }}"></div>`

Answer (score 5):

This should work

```
<div [attr.my-attribute]="'value.to.translate' | translate"></div>
```